# Which php.ini to choose as configuration file?

Tags: php

In my vps:

```
php  -v
```

PHP 7.2.10 (cli) (built: Sep 11 2018 11:22:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

```
php72  -v
```

PHP 7.2.10 (cli) (built: Sep 11 2018 10:09:51) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Two php.ini there.

```
php  --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
php72  --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/opt/remi/php72
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/10-opcache.ini,
```

To select `/etc/opt/remi/php72`  or `/etc/php.ini`  as my configuration?

Comment: depend on which php you want to use.

Comment: You have two PHP installations, so you have two configuration files.

Comment: why have you installed both base anc SCL version ?
Probably you can remove all the php72* package, only keep the php* ones and so use /etc/php.ini (BTW, don't change php.ini, but prefer a php.d/somename.ini)